# GeoDjango: Calculate if someone inside circle from given point

Tags: postgresql, geodjango, geofencing

I am working in GeoDjango (with a Django 1.11 and PostGIS 2.1.4 backend). I have a model with shops in my database (i have the address of this shops) and I am trying to find all shops within 100m radius of the given address.

Comment: @jbchurchill Until now nothing, i was in search for a place to start, right now i'm looking at this tutorial, dunno if it works: http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/shops-near-you-geographic-features-geodjango/